# Trying to add Custom Post Type to this functions.php command

Tags: php, functions

How do I add my Custom Post Type "Single" items to this functions command?

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () {
  if( is_tax('country') || is_page('4090') ){
?>
  <style>
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .site-content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
  }
  </style>
<?php
  }
} );
```

The above works great but I would also like to apply it to my Custom Post Type that is called:

```
conference_2021
```

I'd like the same function to apply also to all pages within the CPT "conference_2021"

I thought this would work but it doesn't:

```
if( is_single('conference_2021') || is_tax('country') || is_page('4090') ){
```

Am I missing something when trying to apply this to a CPT?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/

Answer (score 0):

Both is check single post existing or not.

But both function argument is different.

**is_singular()**. Pass argument for this post type slug

**is_single()** Pass argument for post ID, slug, title.

If you are use **is_single()** then check post type name.

Like:
if ( is_single() && 'conference_2021' == get_post_type() ) { }

**Ref:**
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/

Comment: Yes, `is_singular()` should be used, but the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) for `is_single()` says, "Works for any post type, except attachments and pages". - and the main difference between the functions, is that `is_singular()` accepts a post type slug, whereas `is_single()` accepts the post data like ID or slug.

Comment: yes right. i updated my answer